# Pedal order in vehicles that drive on the left

Tags: car-rentals, automobiles

So this occurred to me a short while ago. I drive a standard in the United States. I know that in several other countries traffic is on the left side of the road instead of the right when you are looking down the length of the road. In those countries, the drivers side is still closer to the centerline placing the driver on the right side of the vehicle.

What would be the left to right order of clutch brake and throttle hand or foot brake under the dash in one of those countries?

Comment: Try braking with your left foot some time. Then you'll realise why the order stays the same

Comment: Most Americans that drive and automatic even though they're not supposed to have gotten into the bad habit of breaking with their left foot. You can tell these people on the road because they're accelerating with their brake lights on or breaking up hills or any number of really stupid things. Everywhere else and people that drive correctly have learned that the fastest way to start slowing down is to take your foot off the accelerator and then usually if you have enough following distance you don't actually need to apply the brakes.

Comment: I'm guessing the people who do this haven't driven cars with a clutch though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s C B A regardless of which side of the road you drive on.

Clutch Brake Accelerator

If you don’t have a clutch. It’s B A

The location of a floor mounted pedal or pull-and-twist type parking brake may be on either side. Parking brakes that fit between the seats are always between the seats.

If the manual or automatic gearshift is floor mounted, then it’ll also be between the seats and thus flip sides. Stalk mounted shifters for automatic transmissions are mounted rather randomly on either side — as are the turn signals and windshield wiper controls.

Comment: Don't forget the gearshift/ gear lever, which is usually in the middle, but might not be.

Comment: I was just thinking of that. The shift lever is usually in line with a transmission on a manual vehicle so that would imply that I would need to learn how to shift with the other hand if I went to one of those countries and rented a vehicle that wasn't an automagic. I don't particularly care for automagic vehicles. They can be an active hindrance in winter driving conditions.

Comment: Your brain can flip the manual shifter over pretty easily as it’s always between the seats. Somehow, my brain can’t flip the turn signal stalk over as easily so I’m constantly washing my rental car’s windshield when I’m traveling to japan.

Comment: Hybrid vehicles have Brake and Accelerator with a Forward/Reverse selector on the dash - they don't have a gearbox. Electrics are similar, but the 2018 Nissan Leaf has an optional single pedal mode: down to go forward, and lift to slow and apply brakes.

Comment: @Airsick: Is that a UK universal?  I'm sure my sister's U.S. hybrid doesn't have a gearbox, but I _know_ it has a shift stick that looks and works like those of petrol-only cars.

Comment: @RoboKaren I have stalk confusion just between cars in the US.  I drive a Ford where the wiper is "twist the left stalk on the left, except it's move the right stalk up and down on my other car, a Ford. Yes, I said Ford twice.  Rowan it really helps to know the particular personality of that auto trans.  These days the manual shifter's position is notional; the transmission is between the front wheels on most cars and there's an elaborate linkage.

Comment: @WGroleau Can't speak for the UK, (I'm in NZ) but it's true for every hybrid I've been in. Thinking about it they were all Japanese.

Comment: @Airsick, I have a 2009 Toyota Prius in the UK and the F/R selector is a short stick on the center console, about where a manual shifter would be (though my US 2001 Prius did have it on the dash). The turn signal stalk is on the left side of the steering column, where I expect it, though other UK cars I've driven have had it on the right by the door.